# getting error while updating elasticsearch version from 2.3.3 to 5.6.3

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

My project is using spring-boot 1.3.5 and I am trying to update elastic search version in my project from 2.3.3 to 5.6.3 and i am creating client using following step:-

```
 Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
```

But when i have run my program it giving me following error:-

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOfProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.createContextSelector(Log4jContextFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:45)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.ESLoggerFactory.getLogger(ESLoggerFactory.java:66)
```

But if i upgrade spring-boot version from 1.3.5 to 1.5.8 then elastic search 5.6.3 was running. 
I am using following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>delete-by-query</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-rc1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

Pleas suggest me how can i resole that error with spring-boot 1.3.5

Comment: Your dependencies seems correct. It is probably an older version of log4j being present on your classpath. How did you launch your application? (standalone, on a server, on your dev machine... ?). Did you perform `mvn clean` before packaging or launching?

Comment: I am using desktop application and also perform mvn clean insatll .

Comment: You mention Spring boot, isn't there other dependencies in your pom.xml? Please shere your entire pom, other dependencies may cause your issue.